# Show UISearchController when tableView swipe down

Tags: ios, swift, search

I implemented the search bar in my test application via UISearchController. when I start my app, I see the search bar under the navigation controller. but how i can hide it when app is starts and show it only when I pull a table view down? and hide again when pull up a table view? I can't find any solution in google or youtube, please help.

**EDIT:**
this is how I implement the UISearchController in `viewDidLoad`

```
//set the searchController
searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search your restaurant"
tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
definesPresentationContext = true

tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0), atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Top, animated: false)
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Place the following segment in your `viewDidLoad`, so whats happening is your asking the `UITableView` to scroll and hide the `SearchBar` at the beginning :

```
tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0), atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Top, animated: false)
```

And don't forget to set the `TableViewHeader` to your `searchController` :

```
tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
```

**Update:**

Because you have an empty tableview then replace the following :

`tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0), atScrollPosition: UITableViewScrollPosition.Top, animated: false)`

With :

```
self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0.0, 44.0)
```

Good luck !

Comment: it's not working. I get this error:
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[UITableView _contentOffsetForScrollingToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:]: row (0) beyond bounds (0) for section (0).'

Comment: What exactly are you using `UISearchBar` or `UISearchController` ? how did you implement the code ?

Comment: @JackDaniel , its not working the way you want ? its not hiding the search bar ?

Comment: @Aaoli, after adding your method, it give me the error:Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '-[UITableView _contentOffsetForScrollingToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:]: row (0) beyond bounds (0) for section (0).' Application starting and crushed in LaunchScreen

Comment: @JackDaniel, Is you tableview empty of data ?

Comment: yes, when the app starting in the first time, tableView must be empty.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91774/discussion-between-aaoii-and-jack-daniel).

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3:**

Just after viewController appeared, you can scroll tableview to section 0, row 0 without animation.

In such a way tableHeaderView with the search bar would not be visible since it is located above section 0.

You simply scroll down the usual way to make it visible.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0), at: UITableViewScrollPosition.top, animated: false)

}
```

Comment: Explain you answer