# How is this implemented in swift 4?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uisearchbar, uisearchbardelegate

I have this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32923091/show-uisearchcontroller-when-tableview-swipe-down) for a pull down search bar in a table view. I was able to implement the search bar in the tableview with this code

```
  searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self 
    searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    searchController.searchBar.placeholder = ""
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        navigationItem.searchController = searchController
    } else {
        self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
    }
    definesPresentationContext = true
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
```

I would want to implement the search function now however I am not able to get the text value in the searchbar. Can anyone provide any hints on how to properly implement this? thank you.

EDIT:

This is the viewWillAppear part to hide the searchbar when the view shows up. I have another problem now. If I start to edit the searchbar totally hides from the view. if I remove `searchController.searchBar.delegate = self` then the searchbar wont hide.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0,y :60.0)
}
```

Comment: Please read the [Ray Wenderlich UISearchController tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/157864/uisearchcontroller-tutorial-getting-started)

Comment: I am not able to get the text value in the searchbar. ? what you are not getting ?

Comment: I am trying to print searchText  from func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String). I am not getting anything here

Comment: I will read it vadian. Thank you

Comment: @jiren Did you set searchController.searchResultsUpdater to your ViewController?

Comment: @Teetz Yes I was able to set that but still not able to get anything

Comment: @jiren show us the code where you setting it and show the UISearchResultsUpdating delegate method then.

Comment: Sorry about that I thought I save the edit. Please check the edited question. Thank you @Teetz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of setting `searchController.searchBar.delegate = self` i would recommend to use the `UISearchResultsUpdating` protocol.

```
import UIKit

class MyViewController: UIViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
        searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        searchController.searchBar.placeholder = ""
        searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false

        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            navigationItem.searchController = searchController
        } else {
            self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
        }
        definesPresentationContext = true
        //searchController.searchBar.delegate = self        <--- you don't need this
    }

    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        if let searchString = searchController.searchBar.text {
            print(searchString)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I can get the searchString now however I am not sure why the searchbar is automatically hiding when I click to edit the searchbar.

Comment: @jiren try to add this to your searchController: 
        `searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false`
     let me know if it helps then i can edit my answer.

Comment: This did the job @Teetz. Thanks a lot

Comment: @jiren glad i could help. Edited my answer and added this line.